# multiple SQL counts using multiple queries using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do multiple counts. I have about 6 columns. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(C.ID) as 'Column 1',
COUNT(C.ID) as 'Column 2',
COUNT(C.ID) as 'Column 3',
COUNT(C.ID) as 'Column 4',
FROM CONTACT C
```

I need to be able to run different counts using different queries but unsure how to apply queries counts in one result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options here.

1) use subqueries as @TheSoultion proposed

2) use use UNION

```
   SELECT 'A' NAME, COUNT(c.ID) [COUNT] FROM Contact c WHERE ... 
   UNION
   SELECT 'B' NAME, COUNT(c.ID) [COUNT] FROM Contact c WHERE ...
```

3) in case it is really the same subset but you want to sum based on some conditions, use case when then inside your counts

```
 SELECT sum(case ... when ... then 1 else 0 end) counta,
        sum(case ... when ... then 1 else 0 end) countb
 FROM ... WHERE ...
```

Comment: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'London' to data type int.` - i get this when using UNION...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I usually end up doing it this way:

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN Condition1 THEN 1 END) AS Column1,
SUM(CASE WHEN Condition2 THEN 1 END) AS Column2
FROM Contact
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run sub queries, or at least that's one way:

```
SELECT
    ( SELECT COUNT(c.ID) FROM Contact c WHERE ... ) AS Column1,
    ( SELECT COUNT(c.ID) FROM Contact c WHERE ... ) AS Column2
```

Comment: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: @PriceCheaperton, and what `WHERE` clause did you use?